# Match multiple patterns in any order in any location in a string

Tags: regex, r

What is the shortest way to use grep to match multiple patterns in any order, in any location in a string? Preferably using base R in one short line.

Here's an example:

I want to find all elements that contain **all** of these two elements in my `matches` vector, in **any order**, in **any location** together in the elements of `my_vector`, with any characters in between them within the element.

```
matches <- c("fe", "ve")

#                1    2    3      4        5       6       7       8      9
my_vector <- c("fv", "v", "f", "f_v_e", "fe_ve", "feve", "vefe", "fve" , "a")

# want 5, 6, 7
```

I can do this:

```
grep(paste0("(?=.*", paste0(matches, sep = ""), ")", collapse = ""), 
     my_vector, 
     perl = TRUE)

[1] 5 6 7
```

But is there a more concise method? In my example I have two elements to match, but my actual problem has several.

Comment: @user2100721 - where is `fe` in 8?

Comment: @user2100721 - *I want to find all elements that contain **all** of these two elements*

Comment: @thelatemail : Ooh...sorry. I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An option to avoid the `regex/paste` would be

```
which(grepl(matches[1], my_vector) & grepl(matches[2],my_vector))
#[1] 5 6 7
```

To make it more dynamic

```
which(Reduce(`&`, lapply(matches, grepl, my_vector)))
#[1] 5 6 7
```

Or as @Jota mentioned `grep` can be used `intersect`

```
Reduce(intersect, lapply(matches, grep, my_vector))
```

If there are many elements in `matches`, the `paste` method may not work...

Comment: similarly: `Reduce(intersect, lapply(matches, grep, my_vector))`

Comment: To use with pipes: `my_df %>%
  filter(Reduce(`&`, lapply(matches, grepl, my_column)))` with backticks around the & (not sure how to get that in a comment!)